# Do a GPS device needs Internet Connection?

Tags: android, arduino, geolocation, gps

Actually I have lots of questions. I am developing a GPS device which gets the longitude and latitude location coordinates. Do I need any internet module? Can I use the device without any internet connection? Also, is it possible to get the coordinates and display it on my Application via Google Maps? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Generally GNSS devices do not need internet for coordinates. However, the coordinates gotten from GNSS satellites lack precision, as a result of this, you sometimes want to get corrections from another device (which has more precise and accurate coordinates).

These corrections can come from the internet.

So generally No you do not need an internet connection for your device to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the device's embedded GPS, you can get the longitude and latitude with no problem, without having any Internet access.

You can then use those coordinates however you'd like, so yes on Google Maps for example. Nevertheless, if you plan to use a Google Maps online API (for instance, the JavaScript API) you'll need an Internet connection to download and display the map. But there should be a way to use pre-downloaded maps offline, you will surely find it in the Google Maps API reference : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/

You can also take a look at some other mapping service providers ([OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) is one of the most used in replacement of Google Maps).

Sorry for not bringing a very precise answer concerning offline maps, but I hope this will help you with your issue :)

**EDIT**

It appears that it isn't possible to legally use the Google Maps API without an Internet Connection, according to Google Maps' [Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/)

Comment: I am planning to use Google Maps, which clearly means I would be using an Internet Connection for my application right, but not for the device? Thank  you.

Comment: @lolomo The device does not require Internet connection in order to get latitude and longitude from GPS, but you'll need an Internet connection to use the Google Maps API, according to the [terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/) :
_1.3 Accounts. Customer must have an Account to access the Admin Console through which Customer may administer its use of the Services._
If Google Maps isn't mandatory maybe you could use another mapping service ?
I'll edit my answer to indiquate that it is legally impossible to use Google Maps offline, sorry.

Comment: I am using Google Maps online for my application. I needed to get the lat and long from the embedded GPS on my device, for me to be able to display it on Google Maps. I am confused on how I will connect my device to my app. I have a code which gets my phone's current location, but not the device's lcoation.